# Can CCM create command use a locally installed version?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, ccm

I'm trying to create a Cassandra Cluster locally on a single Windows 64 bit machine and followed [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199466/how-can-i-create-a-local-multi-node-cassandra-cluster-on-windows-7-64-bit) instructions.

I already have Cassandra 3.7 locally installed and was assuming there'd be a way to make use of the same installation through ccm. But it looks like, ccm always tries to download and install the Cassandra version. Looking into the ccm create [options] didn't provide me a pointer.

Does [this](http://zcourts.com/2011/07/09/setting-up-a-multi-node-cassandra-cluster-on-a-single-windows-machine/#sthash.82lE63nv.dpbs) needs to be followed instead for an already installed one?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cluster with ccm by using the `--install-dir=` parameter as described in the [README](https://github.com/pcmanus/ccm#longer-version).

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried that. It still looks for the build.xml in the installation, which is not there ...

Comment: It looks for a 0.version.txt prior to looking for build.xml. This should contain the version. If that isn't working, I'd suggest that the install dir you are passing isn't correct. If this is a windows machine you need to pass an absolute path.